# How do I add IOperationInvoker to wcf client

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to add my own IOperationInvoker to a wcf client but can't get it to work.
I have this

```
class ClientProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CreateClient().SomeMethod();
    }

    private static MyServiceClient CreateClient()
    {
        var client = new MyServiceClient(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress"net.tcp://localhost:12345/MyService"));
        // I guess this is where the magic should happen
        return client;
    }
}

public class MyOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    private readonly IOperationInvoker _innerOperationInvoker;

    public MyOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker innerOperationInvoker)
    {
        _innerOperationInvoker = innerOperationInvoker;
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Intercepting...");
        return _innerOperationInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
    }

    // Other methods not important
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have something mixed up here.

The `IOperationInvoker` is a server-side only extension point. It allows you to inspect an incoming message and invoke a particular operation on the service based on that message (its content, headers - whatever).

On the client side, this doesn't make sense at all - there's no way a client can use a `IOperationInvoker` implementation.

If you want to know how to add an `IOperationInvoker` implementation on the server-side, check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mahjayar/archive/2007/03/14/wcf-extensibility-plugging-in-custom-message-processing-logic.aspx) for a complete run-down.

For an excellent general-purpose introduction to WCF extensibility, check out Aaron Skonnards [MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx).

Marc

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to add exception handling to all methods in the service client, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm desperately trying to extend the generated `ClientBase<TChannel>` class so that it independently takes care off ALL its exceptions AND unexpected server-replies and routes them all up to a single place or event handler where it will be decided if they tunnel up or handled. See my [bounty-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734660/wcf-client-side-error-handling) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be better served implementing an [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) extension instead.

Comment: Note that `IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply()` doesn't get called when there isn't any message back from the server, in case of `EndpointNotFoundException` or `TimeoutException` for example.

Answer (score -3):

You have missed IOperationBehavior

```
public class MyOperationBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new MyOperationInvoker();
    }
}
```